# how to select records with join in table in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

i need to select the records of the logged in tea(teachers) I've did a lot of research over this but hit a road block after road block, so I really hope your help in this, many thanks!

Here is my code:

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `app` left join `par` on par.par_id=app.par_id
                            left join `tea` on tea.tea_id=app.tea_id
                            ORDER BY app_id DESC");
```

Comment: where is you **where** clause ?

Comment: Please could you edit your question to show what happens when this is running? is any data actually coming back? are you getting an error? Have you tried running the query manually?

Comment: `select * from app left join par on par.par_id=app.par_id
        left join `tea` on tea.tea_id=app.tea_id
           where '".$_SESSION['tea_id']."' ORDER BY app_id DESC"` **i tried this but it doesnt work**

Comment: Questions with SQL queries need: table definitions, sample data set, desired output, query you tried up to now.  If you want to add details to the question, edit it, do not put it in comments.  This way your question is complete, and SO members do not need to read all comments to know what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where clause needs to say which column your matching on

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * 
    from app 
    left join par on par.par_id=app.par_id 
    left join tea on tea.tea_id=app.tea_id 
    where tea.tea_id = '".$_SESSION['tea_id']."' 
    ORDER BY app_id DESC");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your where condition syntax is wrong

```
select * from app 
left join par on par.par_id=app.par_id 
left join tea on tea.tea_id=app.tea_id 
where tea.tea_id = '".$_SESSION['tea_id']."' ORDER BY app_id DESC
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Column 'tea_id' in where clause is ambiguous' in C:\wamp\www\PROJ\app\tea_appview.php on line 135                             
( ! ) Exception: Column 'tea_id' in where clause is ambiguous in C:\wamp\www\PROJ\app\tea_appview.php on line 135

Comment: you can add tea.tea_id in where clause